# PHP: Get Version of ICU

Tags: php, yii2, icu, intl

My production site just provides the old ICU version 4.2.1. Since Yii2 requires Version 49.1 or higher I need to make workarounds in PHP.

How do I get the nersion number of ICU (libicu) which is used by PHP during runtime. Since I have frequent production updates I need to get the version number dynamically in PHP code, e.g. by

```
$libIcuVersion = ...
```

The version number is shown in `phpinfo.php` but the output cannot be used in my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: get ICU version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996249/php-get-icu-version)

Answer (score 3):

This is how [Symfony/Intl](https://github.com/symfony/intl) does it in `Symfony\Component\Intl::getIcuVersion()`.

```php
try {
    $reflector = new \ReflectionExtension('intl');
    ob_start();
    $reflector->info();
    $output = strip_tags(ob_get_clean());
    preg_match('/^ICU version (?:=>)?(.*)$/m', $output, $matches);
    $icuVersion = trim($matches[1]);
} catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
    $icuVersion = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 php -r "echo phpinfo();" |grep -i 'icu'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this slightly modified method that Yii 2 is using:

```
function checkPhpExtensionVersion($extensionName)
{
    if (!extension_loaded($extensionName)) {
        return false;
    }
    $extensionVersion = phpversion($extensionName);
    if (empty($extensionVersion)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (strncasecmp($extensionVersion, 'PECL-', 5) === 0) {
        $extensionVersion = substr($extensionVersion, 5);
    }

    return $extensionVersion;
}
```

Comment: This showed me a version of php_intl extension version (1.1.0 in my case with PHP 7.2.1), not ICU library version which is 60.1 according to phpinfo() output.

Answer (score 1):

I would get and parse phpinfo() results.

```
<?php

// get ICU library version in current PHP

// check environment
if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli") {
    exit('This only works in PHP command line (unless you write phpinfo()\'s html parser)');
}

// get phpinfo() std output into buffer
ob_start();
phpinfo();

// search all buffer starting with 'ICU'
preg_match_all(
    '/^(?P<name>ICU(?: [A-Za-z_]*)? version) => (?P<version>.*)$/m',
    ob_get_clean(),
    $matched,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
if (count($matched) === 0) {
    exit('no ICU library info found in phpinfo(). Your PHP may not have php_intl extension turned on.');
}
foreach($matched as $current) {
    echo $current['name'] . ": " . $current['version'] . PHP_EOL;
}

/* output sample

ICU version:60.1
ICU Data version:60.1
ICU TZData version:2017c
ICU Unicode version:10.0

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried akky's version. But it didn't work for me. After some effort I ended up with the following:

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$icudata = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

preg_match_all(
    '/<tr><td[^>]*>(ICU(?: [A-Za-z_]*)? version)[^<]*<\/td><td[^>]*>([^<]*)/',
    $icudata,
    $matches
);

$count = sizeof($matches[0]);
if ($count == 0) 
  echo 'no ICU library info found in phpinfo(). Your PHP may not have php_intl extension turned on.';
else
{ for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    echo $matches[1][$i] . ": " .trim($matches[2][$i]) . '<br>';
}
```