# PHP: get ICU version

Tags: php, icu, intl

Is there a vay to get ICU version in PHP? With phpversion() I only managed to get the intl version, but I need to compare the ICU version to workaround some servers that have an older ICU version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INTL_ICU_VERSION` constant for that. It was [added many years ago](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/?view=revision&revision=311714), though doesn't appear to have been documented.

Comment: It is documented now, thanks for the warning. https://news-web.php.net/php.doc.cvs/17452 In the future for speedier changes please use the Edit button on the PHP handbook page. https://i.imgur.com/lJ93ke7.png Thanks!

Comment: @chx Not using that god awful web editor is a healthy life decision. People with commit access to docs knew about this constant missing years ago and didn't bother doing anything about it - complain at them, not me.

Comment: I have commit access and I didn't know. The moment I learned about it I have fixed it.