# Discover skeletons supported by PHP's IntlDatePatternGenerator

Tags: php, icu

I'm trying to use PHP's `IntlDatePatternGenerator` class.  Is there a way, other than trial and error, to find out what skeletons are supported by the `getBestPattern()` method?

Even if it involves looking in a system file somewhere, that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

`IntlDatePatternGenerator` is a wrapper around [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/), and according to the [docs](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/):

> A full list of date and time symbols that can be used in skeleton strings (input to `DateTimePatternGenerator`) can be found in the [UTS 35 (LDML) Date Field Symbol Table](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table).

To the best of my knowledge, PHP passes through directly so I think that list is the most authoritative.

Comment: Whilst that gives a full list of symbols that can be used, the only skeleton string that I have found in practice to generate patterns is 'MMMMy'.   I suspect that only a subset of the possible combinations is supported in reality.  A method such as `getSkeletons()` would be useful but doesn't seem to exist.  Presumably somewhere in the ICU files there will be a list of supported skeletons, but I can't work out where.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know a whole lot about the this system, but testing a bunch of those symbols/patterns appears to be working as far as I can tell: https://3v4l.org/lVRqP#v8.1.18

Comment: Thanks. I tried that code on my system and all I get is an empty string.  Whereas if I set `$skeleton = 'MMMMy';` then I get "April 2023".  That's why I think the support for skeletons must be system dependent and maybe not all the skeleton mappings are installed on my system.  I'll do some more digging.

Comment: It might be helpful to check the version of ICU this is referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59023115/231316

Comment: Also, just ignoring the date, can you inspect the patterns returned? https://3v4l.org/8UDHP#v8.1.18

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've got it working now.  I'm embarrassed to admit that it was an error in my setup!  Thanks for your time.